# How can I get a list of the available NSFont families?

Tags: ios, objective-c, list, cocoa, fonts

How can I get a list of the available NSFont families, preferably with the fontName: equivalents.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFontFamilies] description]);
```

Gives:

```
"Abadi MT Condensed Extra Bold",
"Abadi MT Condensed Light",
"Academy Engraved LET",
"Al Bayan",
"American Typewriter",
"Andale Mono",
Arial,
"Arial Black",
"Arial Hebrew",
"Arial Narrow",
"Arial Rounded MT Bold",
"Arial Unicode MS",
Ayuthaya,
Baghdad,
"Bank Gothic",
Baskerville,
"Baskerville Old Face",
Batang,
"Bauhaus 93",
"Bell MT",
"Bernard MT Condensed",
BiauKai,
"Big Caslon",
"Birch Std",
"Blackmoor LET",
"Blackoak Std",
"BlairMdITC TT",
"Bodoni Ornaments ITC TT",
"Bodoni SvtyTwo ITC TT",
"Bodoni SvtyTwo OS ITC TT",
"Bodoni SvtyTwo SC ITC TT",
"Book Antiqua",
"Bookman Old Style",
"Bookshelf Symbol 7",
"Bordeaux Roman Bold LET",
"Bradley Hand ITC TT",
Braggadocio,
"Britannic Bold",
"Brush Script MT",
"Brush Script Std",
Calibri,
"Calisto MT",
Cambria,
Candara,
Capitals,
Casual,
Century,
"Century Gothic",
"Century Schoolbook",
Chalkboard,
Chalkduster,
"Chaparral Pro",
"Charcoal CY",
"Charlemagne Std",
Cochin,
"Colonna MT",
"Comic Sans MS",
Consolas,
Constantia,
"Cooper Black",
"Cooper Std",
Copperplate,
"Copperplate Gothic Bold",
"Copperplate Gothic Light",
Corbel,
"Corsiva Hebrew",
Courier,
"Courier New",
Cracked,
"Curlz MT",
"DecoType Naskh",
Desdemona,
"Devanagari MT",
Didot,
"Edwardian Script ITC",
"Engravers MT",
"Euphemia UCAS",
Eurostile,
"Footlight MT Light",
"Franklin Gothic Book",
"Franklin Gothic Medium",
Futura,
Garamond,
"GB18030 Bitmap",
"Geeza Pro",
Geneva,
"Geneva CY",
Georgia,
"Giddyup Std",
"Gill Sans",
"Gill Sans MT",
"Gill Sans Ultra Bold",
"Gloucester MT Extra Condensed",
"Goudy Old Style",
"Gujarati MT",
Gulim,
GungSeo,
"Gurmukhi MT",
Haettenschweiler,
"Handwriting - Dakota",
Harrington,
HeadLineA,
Hei,
"Heiti SC",
"Heiti TC",
Helvetica,
"Helvetica CY",
"Helvetica Neue",
Herculanum,
"Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",
"Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN",
"Hiragino Kaku Gothic Std",
"Hiragino Kaku Gothic StdN",
"Hiragino Maru Gothic Pro",
"Hiragino Maru Gothic ProN",
"Hiragino Mincho Pro",
"Hiragino Mincho ProN",
"Hiragino Sans GB",
"Hobo Std",
"Hoefler Text",
Impact,
"Imprint MT Shadow",
InaiMathi,
"Jazz LET",
Kai,
Kailasa,
"Kino MT",
Kokonor,
"Kozuka Gothic Pr6N",
"Kozuka Gothic Pro",
"Kozuka Mincho Pr6N",
"Kozuka Mincho Pro",
Krungthep,
KufiStandardGK,
"Letter Gothic Std",
"LiHei Pro",
"LiSong Pro",
"Lithos Pro",
"Lucida Blackletter",
"Lucida Bright",
"Lucida Calligraphy",
"Lucida Console",
"Lucida Fax",
"Lucida Grande",
"Lucida Handwriting",
"Lucida Sans",
"Lucida Sans Typewriter",
"Lucida Sans Unicode",
"Marker Felt",
Marlett,
"Matura MT Script Capitals",
Meiryo,
Menlo,
"Mesquite Std",
"Microsoft Sans Serif",
"Minion Pro",
Mistral,
"Modern No. 20",
"Mona Lisa Solid ITC TT",
Monaco,
"MS Gothic",
"MS Mincho",
"MS PGothic",
"MS PMincho",
"MS Reference Sans Serif",
"MS Reference Specialty",
Mshtakan,
"MT Extra",
"Myriad Pro",
Nadeem,
"New Peninim MT",
"News Gothic MT",
"Nueva Std",
"OCR A Std",
Onyx,
Optima,
"Orator Std",
Osaka,
Palatino,
Papyrus,
"Party LET",
PCMyungjo,
Perpetua,
"Perpetua Titling MT",
PilGi,
"Plantagenet Cherokee",
Playbill,
PMingLiU,
"Poplar Std",
"PortagoITC TT",
"Prestige Elite Std",
"Princetown LET",
Raanana,
Rockwell,
"Rockwell Extra Bold",
"Rosewood Std",
"Santa Fe LET",
Sathu,
"Savoye LET",
"SchoolHouse Cursive B",
"SchoolHouse Printed A",
Silom,
SimSun,
Skia,
"Snell Roundhand",
Stencil,
"Stencil Std",
STFangsong,
STHeiti,
STKaiti,
"Stone Sans ITC TT",
"Stone Sans Sem ITC TT",
STSong,
Symbol,
"Synchro LET",
Tahoma,
"Tekton Pro",
Thonburi,
Times,
"Times New Roman",
"Trajan Pro",
"Trebuchet MS",
"Tw Cen MT",
"Type Embellishments One LET",
Verdana,
Webdings,
"Wide Latin",
Wingdings,
"Wingdings 2",
"Wingdings 3",
"Zapf Dingbats",
Zapfino,
"Adobe Arabic",
"Adobe Caslon Pro",
"Adobe Fan Heiti Std",
"Adobe Fangsong Std",
"Adobe Garamond Pro",
"Adobe Gothic Std",
"Adobe Hebrew",
"Adobe Heiti Std",
"Adobe Kaiti Std",
"Adobe Ming Std",
"Adobe Myungjo Std",
"Adobe Song Std",
"Apple Braille",
"Apple Chancery",
"Apple Garamond BT",
"Apple LiGothic",
"Apple LiSung",
"Apple Symbols",
AppleGothic,
AppleMyungjo,
"Monotype Corsiva",
"Monotype Sorts"
```

in 10.6.4

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5**

```
for family in NSFontManager.shared.availableFontFamilies {
    print(family)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFontFamilies]
```

(previously, I had written `-[NSFontManager availableFontFamilies]`, which is a conventional way of writing a method name, but could be confusing if interpreted as sample code.)

Comment: Yeah, must have missed it, I was digging around in the documentation for NSFont ...

Answer (score 5):

Here's how it can be done for Swift:

```
let fontFamilyNames = NSFontManager.sharedFontManager().availableFontFamilies

print("avaialble fonts is \(fontFamilyNames)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Apple's documentation, for instance: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5379.

-[NSFontManager availableFontFamilies] may reveal fonts that are not a part of the version of OS X you are targeting (I think this is beacause they were loaded with other applications, for example Adobe Illustrator).

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface FontController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *text;
}
- (IBAction)takeFontFamilyFrom: (id)sender;
- (IBAction)takeFontSizeFrom: (id)sender;
- (IBAction)takeFontAttributeFrom: (id)sender;
@end

#import "FontController.h"

NSFontManager *fm;

@implementation FontController
+ (void)initialize
{
    fm = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
}
- (IBAction)takeFontFamilyFrom: (id)sender
{
    NSFont *font = [text font];
    font = [fm convertFont: font
                  toFamily: [sender stringValue]];
    [text setFont: font];
}
- (IBAction)takeFontSizeFrom: (id)sender
{
    NSFont *font = [text font];
    font = [fm convertFont: font
                    toSize: [sender doubleValue]];
    [text setFont: font];
}

- (IBAction)takeFontAttributeFrom: (id)sender
{
    NSFont *font = [text font];
    NSFontTraitMask attribute = [sender tag];
    if (NSOnState == [sender state])
    {
        font = [fm convertFont: font toHaveTrait: attribute];
    }
    else
    {
        font = [fm convertFont: font toNotHaveTrait: attribute];
    }
    [sender setState: ([fm traitsOfFont: font] & attribute)];
    [text setFont: font];
}
@end
```